# Magento admin login and admin panel are extremely slow

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

I have problem with speed of magento admin panel, login in backend and other sections of admin panel are very extremely slow.
I did all items in below links but speed did not change:

1. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-speed-up-magento-admin-panel/
2. [Speeding up magento backend (now slow)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/speeding-up-magento-backend-now-slow)
3. https://suyati.com/blog/speed-up-magento-admin-backend/

Answer (score 0):

There will be not perfect version or you using theme for your version 
make sure that you version is updated.... 
download from [Magento download](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)